# Calculating inner product in integral form on an example

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the inner product $(u|v)$ as:

$(u|v) = \int_{0}^1  \overline{u(x)}v(x)e^x dx + \int_{0}^1 \overline{u'(x)}v'(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \qquad$

Where $v(x) = v$

So given that $u = u(x) = x$ i get for the inner product:

$\begin{align}
(u|u) & =  \int_{0}^1  \overline{u(x)}u(x)e^x dx + \int_{0}^1 \overline{u'(x)}u'(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \\
(x|x) & = \int_{0}^1  \overline{x}xe^x dx + \int_{0}^1 \overline{x'}x'\, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 & = \int_{0}^1  \overline{x}xe^x dx + \int_{0}^1 \overline{1}1\, \mathrm{d}x \\
 & = \int_{0}^1  |x|^2e^x dx + \int_{0}^1 1^2\, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 & = e -2
\end{align}
$

However the final answer is supposed to be $(x|x) = (e-\frac{3}{2})$
Now am I approaching this wrong the wrong way or is my answer correct?

Also when $u = u(x)=x$ the inner product $(u|v)$ gives:

$\begin{align}
(u|v) & =  \int_{0}^1  \overline{u(x)}v(x)e^x dx + \int_{0}^1 \overline{u'(x)}v'(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \\
(x|v) & = \int_{0}^1  \overline{x}ve^x dx + \int_{0}^1 \overline{x'}v'\, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 & = \int_{0}^1  \overline{x}ve^x dx + \int_{0}^1 \overline{1}v'\, \mathrm{d}x \\
 & = \int_{0}^1  (xe^x -1) v(x) dx + v(1)
\end{align}
$

Since $v(0) = 0$ the last integral only returns $v(1)$.

But I can't see how

$\int_{0}^1  \overline{x}ve^x dx$

becomes

$\int_{0}^1  (xe^x -1) v(x) dx$

What is going on here?